# Error: elements of array 'Transfer()::StoreS myStructD [2]' have incomplete type

Tags: c++, struct

I am unclear as to why I keep getting the mentioned error.

I declared the struct in a class and then defined it outside.

I even changed from private to protected

```
class Savings : public Account
{
protected: 
    struct StoreS;
};

struct Savings::StoreS
{
    int account_num;
    string type;
    double amount;
    int sent;
};
```

In the transfer function, I then named the struct: `struct StoreS myStructD[2];`

Kindly advise.

Comment: Kindly show the `transfer` function.

Comment: its saying its too long

Comment: Transfer function (without the user prompts)

        void Transfer(){
 
        struct StoreS myStructD[2];
         struct StoreS myStructC[2];
 
        struct Loan myLoan[2];
      Savings oneD[2], oneC[2];
      Personal_Loan two[2];
 
  
  myStructD[count].account_num = firstS[i].getAcc();
  myStructD[count].type="Debit";
  myStructD[count].amount = amount;
  oneD[2].setTrans("Debit", amount);
    

 
}

Comment: The only way I can repro this error is if the definition of the function is before the definition of the struct (which makes sense). Where is Transfer defined? ([see here](https://godbolt.org/z/nWMb6jfEY) you can toggle the FIX_IT define to get the error back)

Comment: I have it in this order
1. class with struck storeS
2. Defintion of struct storeS
3. void Transfer(){}
4. int main

Comment: Is Transfer a member function (and if so which class) or a free function?

Comment: ohhhh i didnt know! (im learning). Thank you will try that. So basically i can go ahead and do this Savings::StoreS myStruckC[2]?

Comment: @Borgleader transfer is on its own just a void transfer(){} by itself.

Comment: if i guessed correctly and its a free function then yes, with member functions wouldnt because your already in the namespace of the Savings class, but a free function needs to specify.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! Had to change the struck from the protected to public in the class but it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do since you haven't shared a [mre].